# Appium inspector is always loading

Tags: mobile, automation, appium-ios, inspector

I'm trying to inspect my iOS application with Appium desktop. So, I open the server and I selected "start inspector session" then I select my capability and start the session. But the inspector is always loading[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmecM.png

This is the server log:

```
[RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "3": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 3, [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "JSContext", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeJavaScript" [RemoteDebugger] } [RemoteDebugger] } [XCUITest] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing: {"appIdKey":"802","pageArray":[{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}]} [XCUITest] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array [XCUITest] We do not appear to have window set yet, ignoring [RemoteDebugger] Sending connection key request [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' message (id: 0): 'setConnectionKey' [RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 4ms [RemoteDebugger] Sending connection key request [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' message (id: 2): 'setConnectionKey' [RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 5ms [RemoteDebugger] Selecting application [RemoteDebugger] No applications currently connected. [XCUITest] No web frames found. [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP"] [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/contexts 200 154 ms - 86 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/context [HTTP] {} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Calling AppiumDriver.getCurrentContext() with args: ["43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b"] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getCurrentContext' [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Responding to client with driver.getCurrentContext() result: "NATIVE_APP" [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/context 200 6 ms - 84 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b [HTTP] {} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Calling AppiumDriver.getSession() with args: ["43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b"] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getSession' [WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'getSession' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E] with no body [RemoteDebugger] Received connected automation availability state: "WIRAutomationAvailabilityNotAvailable" [RemoteDebugger] Received connected applications list: PID:803, PID:802, PID:71 [RemoteDebugger] Received connected driver list: {} [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":"Motorna","sdkVersion":"14.1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.machinesTalk.motorna"}},"sessionId":"586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E"} [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /wda/screen] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E/wda/screen] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"statusBarSize":{"width":414,"height":44},"scale":3},"sessionId":"586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E"} [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E/window/size] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"width":414,"height":896},"sessionId":"586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E"} [XCUITest] Merging WDA caps over Appium caps for session detail response [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Responding to client with driver.getSession() result: {"udid":"00008020-00097D001423002E","automationName":"XCUITest","bundleId":"com.machinesTalk.motorna","deviceName":"XmaxiPhone","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"14.1","xcodeOrgId":"ST4BY654BM","xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true,"device":"iphone","browserName":"Motorna","sdkVersion":"14.1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.machinesTalk.motorna","pixelRatio":3,"statBarHeight":44,"viewportRect":{"left":0,"top":132,"width":1242,"height":2556}} [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b 200 580 ms - 568 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/window/current/size [HTTP] {} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowSize() with args: ["current","43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b"] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getWindowSize' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E/window/size] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"width":414,"height":896},"sessionId":"586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E"} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Responding to client with driver.getWindowSize() result: {"width":414,"height":896} [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/window/current/size 200 60 ms - 98 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/execute [HTTP] {"script":"mobile:getContexts","args":[]} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Calling AppiumDriver.execute() with args: ["mobile:getContexts",[],"43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b"] [XCUITest] Executing command 'execute' [XCUITest] Getting list of available contexts [iOS] Retrieving contexts and views [XCUITest] Selecting by url: false [RemoteDebugger] Sending connection key request [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' message (id: 4): 'setConnectionKey' [RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 4ms [RemoteDebugger] Selecting application [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available: [RemoteDebugger] Application: "PID:803" [RemoteDebugger] id: "PID:803" [RemoteDebugger] isProxy: true [RemoteDebugger] name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent" [RemoteDebugger] bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent" [RemoteDebugger] hostId: "PID:802" [RemoteDebugger] isActive: true [RemoteDebugger] isAutomationEnabled: "Unknown" [RemoteDebugger] Application: "PID:802" [RemoteDebugger] id: "PID:802" [RemoteDebugger] isProxy: false [RemoteDebugger] name: "Motorna" [RemoteDebugger] bundleId: "com.machinesTalk.motorna" [RemoteDebugger] hostId: undefined [RemoteDebugger] isActive: true [RemoteDebugger] isAutomationEnabled: "Unknown" [RemoteDebugger] Checking for bundle identifiers: com.apple.WebKit.WebContent, process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent, process-SafariViewService, com.apple.SafariViewService, *, com.machinesTalk.motorna [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:803' for bundle 'com.apple.WebKit.WebContent' [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:803' for bundle 'process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent' [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:803' for bundle 'process-SafariViewService' [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:803' for bundle 'com.apple.SafariViewService' [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:803' for bundle '*' [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:802' for bundle 'com.machinesTalk.motorna' [RemoteDebugger] Found separate bundleId 'process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent' acting as proxy for 'com.machinesTalk.motorna', with app id 'PID:803' [RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:803, PID:802 (try #1 of 20) [RemoteDebugger] Attempting app 'PID:803' [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to app 'PID:803' (id: 6): 'connectToApp' [RemoteDebugger] Received response from send (id: 6): '["PID:803",{}]' [RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 20ms [RemoteDebugger] Empty page dictionary received [RemoteDebugger] Error checking application: 'Empty page dictionary received'. Retrying connection [RemoteDebugger] Attempting app 'PID:802' [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to app 'PID:802' (id: 8): 'connectToApp' [RemoteDebugger] Received response from send (id: 8): '["PID:802",{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWebPage","WIRURLKey":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framewo...' [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: { [RemoteDebugger] "1": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1 [RemoteDebugger] } [RemoteDebugger] } [XCUITest] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing: {"appIdKey":"802","pageArray":[{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}]} [XCUITest] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array [XCUITest] We do not appear to have window set yet, ignoring [RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 20ms [RemoteDebugger] Received page change notice for app 'PID:802' but the listing has not changed. Ignoring. [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: { [RemoteDebugger] "1": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1 [RemoteDebugger] } [RemoteDebugger] } [XCUITest] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing: {"appIdKey":"802","pageArray":[{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}]} [XCUITest] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array [XCUITest] We do not appear to have window set yet, ignoring [RemoteDebugger] Received altered app id, updating from 'null' to 'PID:802' [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available: [RemoteDebugger] Application: "PID:803" [RemoteDebugger] id: "PID:803" [RemoteDebugger] isProxy: true [RemoteDebugger] name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent" [RemoteDebugger] bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent" [RemoteDebugger] hostId: "PID:802" [RemoteDebugger] isActive: true [RemoteDebugger] isAutomationEnabled: "Unknown" [RemoteDebugger] Application: "PID:802" [RemoteDebugger] id: "PID:802" [RemoteDebugger] isProxy: false [RemoteDebugger] name: "Motorna" [RemoteDebugger] bundleId: "com.machinesTalk.motorna" [RemoteDebugger] hostId: undefined [RemoteDebugger] isActive: true [RemoteDebugger] isAutomationEnabled: "Unknown" [RemoteDebugger] pageArray: [RemoteDebugger] - id: 1 [RemoteDebugger] title: "" [RemoteDebugger] url: "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/" [RemoteDebugger] isKey: false [RemoteDebugger] Finally selecting app PID:802: [{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}] [RemoteDebugger] Selected app after 50ms [XCUITest] Found webview context after 55ms [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Responding to client with driver.execute() result: [{"id":"NATIVE_APP"},{"id":"WEBVIEW_802.1","title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","bundleId":"com.machinesTalk.motorna"}] [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/execute 200 56 ms - 297 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/source [HTTP] {} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b"] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getPageSource' [WD Proxy] Matched '/source' to command name 'getPageSource' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /source] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E/source] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":"\n\n \n \n \n \n \n [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Responding to client with driver.getPageSource() result: "\n \n \n \n \n \n [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/source 200 151 ms - 3122 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/screenshot [HTTP] {} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Calling AppiumDriver.getScreenshot() with args: ["43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b"] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getScreenshot' [XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA [WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E/screenshot] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"-[XCUIScreen screenshotDataForQuality:rect:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b25e40","traceback":"(\n\t0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7da5c0 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 1185216\n\t1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001be8c842c objc_exception_throw + 60\n\t2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa6e4a2c 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 178732\n\t3 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7dd130 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 1196336\n\t4 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7df420 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96\n\t5 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102adf93c -[XCUIDevice(FBHelpers) fb_rawScreenshotWithQuality:error:] + 156\n\t6 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102adf808 -[XCUIDevice(FBHelpers) fb_screenshotWithError:] + 88\n\t7 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102a7f350 +[FBScreenshotCommands handleGetScreenshot:] + 1... [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unknown error' to UnknownError [XCUITest] Error getting screenshot: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: -[XCUIScreen screenshotDataForQuality:rect:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b25e40 [XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA [WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E/screenshot] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"-[XCUIScreen screenshotDataForQuality:rect:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b0c680","traceback":"(\n\t0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7da5c0 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 1185216\n\t1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001be8c842c objc_exception_throw + 60\n\t2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa6e4a2c 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 178732\n\t3 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7dd130 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 1196336\n\t4 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7df420 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96\n\t5 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102adf93c -[XCUIDevice(FBHelpers) fb_rawScreenshotWithQuality:error:] + 156\n\t6 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102adf808 -[XCUIDevice(FBHelpers) fb_screenshotWithError:] + 88\n\t7 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102a7f350 +[FBScreenshotCommands handleGetScreenshot:] + 1... [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unknown error' to UnknownError [XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA [WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E/screenshot] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"-[XCUIScreen screenshotDataForQuality:rect:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b00480","traceback":"(\n\t0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7da5c0 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 1185216\n\t1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001be8c842c objc_exception_throw + 60\n\t2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa6e4a2c 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 178732\n\t3 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7dd130 52963DBA-FA89-36C2-8262-28B9776F8C12 + 1196336\n\t4 CoreFoundation 0x00000001aa7df420 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96\n\t5 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102adf93c -[XCUIDevice(FBHelpers) fb_rawScreenshotWithQuality:error:] + 156\n\t6 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102adf808 -[XCUIDevice(FBHelpers) fb_screenshotWithError:] + 88\n\t7 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102a7f350 +[FBScreenshotCommands handleGetScreenshot:] + 1... [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unknown error' to UnknownError [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: -[XCUIScreen screenshotDataForQuality:rect:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b00480 [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] at errorFromW3CJsonCode (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:780:25) [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:663:14) [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] at JWProxy.command (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:273:19) [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] at runMicrotasks () [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5) [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b/screenshot 500 1069 ms - 273 [HTTP] [WebDriverAgent] Parsed BUILD_DIR configuration value: '/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Build/Products' [WebDriverAgent] Got derived data root: '/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp' [RemoteDebugger] We were notified we might have connected to the wrong app. Using id PID:805 instead of PID:802 [RemoteDebugger] We were notified we might have connected to the wrong app. Using id PID:805 instead of PID:802 [RemoteDebugger] Notified that new application 'PID:805' has connected [RemoteDebugger] Notified that new application 'PID:805' has connected [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: { [RemoteDebugger] "1": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "4": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 4 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "5": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 5, [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "JSContext", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeJavaScript" [RemoteDebugger] } [RemoteDebugger] } [XCUITest] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing: {"appIdKey":"802","pageArray":[{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false},{"id":4,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}]} [XCUITest] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array [XCUITest] We do not appear to have window set yet, ignoring [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: { [RemoteDebugger] "1": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "4": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 4 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "5": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 5, [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "JSContext", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeJavaScript" [RemoteDebugger] } [RemoteDebugger] } [XCUITest] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing: {"appIdKey":"802","pageArray":[{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false},{"id":4,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}]} [XCUITest] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array [XCUITest] We do not appear to have window set yet, ignoring [RemoteDebugger] Notified that new application 'PID:807' has connected [RemoteDebugger] Notified that new application 'PID:807' has connected [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: { [RemoteDebugger] "1": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "4": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 4 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "6": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 6 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "7": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 7, [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "JSContext", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeJavaScript" [RemoteDebugger] } [RemoteDebugger] } [XCUITest] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing: {"appIdKey":"802","pageArray":[{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false},{"id":4,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false},{"id":6,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}]} [XCUITest] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array [XCUITest] We do not appear to have window set yet, ignoring [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: { [RemoteDebugger] "1": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "4": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 4 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "6": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWebPage", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRURLKey": "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 6 [RemoteDebugger] }, [RemoteDebugger] "7": { [RemoteDebugger] "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 7, [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTitleKey": "JSContext", [RemoteDebugger] "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeJavaScript" [RemoteDebugger] } [RemoteDebugger] } [XCUITest] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing: {"appIdKey":"802","pageArray":[{"id":1,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false},{"id":4,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false},{"id":6,"title":"","url":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E625C3A-845C-46CB-B481-A7F55901EB76/CarsTalk-R1.app/Frameworks/SwiftR.framework/","isKey":false}]} [XCUITest] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array [XCUITest] We do not appear to have window set yet, ignoring [HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b [HTTP] {} [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b"] [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1620779743495 (02:35:43 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)) [Appium] Removing session 43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b from our master session list [WD Proxy] Matched '/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b' to command name 'deleteSession' [WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/586DDD81-0AE5-428A-B530-02468EB7F18E] with no body [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:802' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'PID:802' [RemoteDebugger] No longer have app id. Attempting to find new one. [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:807' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'undefined' [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:803' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'undefined' [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:805' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'undefined' [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:802' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'PID:802' [RemoteDebugger] No longer have app id. Attempting to find new one. [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:807' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'undefined' [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:803' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'undefined' [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:805' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary. [RemoteDebugger] Current app is 'undefined' [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":null,"sessionId":null} [DevCon Factory] Releasing connections for 00008020-00097D001423002E device on any port number [DevCon Factory] Found cached connections to release: ["00008020-00097D001423002E:8100"] [DevCon Factory] Releasing the listener for '00008020-00097D001423002E:8100' [iProxy@00008020:8100] Closing the connection [DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0 [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use clearSystemFilescapability to turn on. [XCUITest] Found a remote debugger session. Removing... [RemoteDebugger] Disconnecting from remote debugger [RemoteDebugger] Cleaning up listeners [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionFinished' logged at 1620779744527 (02:35:44 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)) [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Received response: null [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] But deleting session, so not returning [MJSONWP (43b20adf)] Responding to client with driver.deleteSession() result: null [HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/43b20adf-95cc-4540-82c9-14a89a80b60b 200 1033 ms - 76 [HTTP]
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Mach! Welcome to StackOverflow.

I have had a similar problem to yours when I had copied the capabilities from the WebDriverIO config to the inspector and the app started on my device but never loaded in the inspector.

[image]

The Appium logs indicated that a "method" was not implemented. Appium wraps the Flutter Driver using one of the platform specific automation Drivers and it needs to know which wrapper to use in the inspector, otherwise it cannot interact with the app. It needs to do this to call `getPageSource()` which is what is displayed in that section that's still loading.

I was testing on an Android device, so I changed my "automationName" field to "UiAutomator2" and it worked for me. For iOS you could try "XCUITest" or "Instruments".

See the [device capabilities docs page](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/index.html) for references to this and the available AutomationNames.

It's also worth noting that Appium requires the following environment variables to bet set or it will be unable to run normally:

- JAVA_HOME
- ANDROID_HOME

Here is a decent reference for configuring and using Appium: [Clarabez's Appium Course (in English)](https://github.com/clarabez/appium-en)

Otherwise, check the Appium server logs themselves for errors or exceptions. You can check them in the window like in my screenshot or log them to a file for reviewing.